# Batch: getting numbers between x and y from string "x123y"

Tags: regex, windows, batch-file

I need to extract the numbers between `su11b_` and `.agm` using batch script. 
In the example below the result should be `733`.

- `su11b_` is always the same, the numbers here will never change
- `733` can change, ranging from 1 - eternity (and will thus have a variable length)

Here's what I tried (and it doesn't work at all):

```
set "str=d:\agrcc\agrtest\server logging\su11b_733.agm"
set /A "number=str"
```

I'm thinking perhaps a regex thingy could extract the digits between `su11b_` and `.agm` but I don't know how to do this in batch scripting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually don't need regex if you're sure the numbers are always between `su11b_` and `.agm`. You can just delete everything before `su11b_` and delete the `.agm` part afterwards:

```
set "var=d:\agrcc\agrtest\server logging\su11b_733.agm"
set number=%var:*su11b_=%
set number=%number:.agm=%
echo %number%
```

[This link](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html) has some more info about replacing substrings in variables in batch

Comment: Nice! Can you explain what these syntaxes do?
`%var:*su11b_=%` and `%number:.agm=%`
I really need to learn this stuff...

Comment: That is string substitution. It basically says `%varname : (replace) stringToReplace = (replace with) stringToReplaceWith%`. This includes te wildcard character `*` as well. So you are first replacing everything in front of your numbers and then removing the file extension.

Comment: @dadde geisterfurz007 already covered it (nice and short). You can follow the link in the post if you want some more info.

Comment: @geisterfurz007 thanks a lot: one little step for the community...but one great leap for me :-D